# React Danger: Discarding unexpected node in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, reactjs

I have the next react component. It works in Chrome, but in Safari it throws

> Danger: Discarding unexpected node: 
>   `<option value=​"1" data-reactid=​".0.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.0.1:​$vivienda.$1">​Apartamento​</option>​`

```
import React from 'react';

export default class SelectorOptgroup extends React.Component{

getOptions(){
   let options = [];
for(let key in this.props.subOption){
 options.push(<option key={key} value={key}>{this.props.subOption[key]}</option>   );
}
return options;
}
render(){
  return (
  <optgroup label={this.props.label}>
    {this.getOptions()}
  </optgroup>
)
}
}
```

Comment: Danger: Discarding unexpected node: 
<option value=​"1" data-reactid=​".0.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.0.1:​$vivienda.$1">​Apartamento​</option>​
main.js:13081Danger: Discarding unexpected node: 
<option value=​"68" data-reactid=​".0.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.0.1:​$vivienda.$68">​Cabaña​</option>​

Comment: Please do not add additional code or information in comments. Edit your original question and add it there instead.